# StateParams passed through function not working using meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meteor, ionic-framework

Here is my function used to retrieve data from the database depending on the parameter `idCats`:

```
  this.getSubcat = function(){

    //Load products on scroll.
    this.subscribe('SubcatIndex', () => [ $stateParams.idCats, self.loaded ], {
      onReady: function() {

        Meteor.call('allSubcats', $stateParams.idCats, function(err, count) {
            self.allsubcats = count;
            self.limit = self.loaded;
            console.log("Test Log: " + $stateParams.idCats);

          self.subcats = Products.find({
            catLinkID : $stateParams.idCats
          },{
              fields: {
                _id: true,
                name: true,
                catLinkID: true,
                idCat: true,
                image: true,
                listingsCount: true,
                productOffersCount: true,
                productSoldCount: true
              }
        }).fetch();

          window.localStorage.setItem('subcats', JSON.stringify(self.subcats) );

          self.contentLoaded = true;
          self.noPosts = 'No posts available.';

          $ionicLoading.hide();
          return;        
        });
      },
      onStop: function(err){

        if(err){
          self.contentLoaded = true;
          self.noPosts = "No internet connection.";
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  this.getSubcat();
```

When i change this line:

```
  self.subcats = Products.find({
    catLinkID : $stateParams.idCats
  }
```

To:

```
  self.subcats = Products.find({
    catLinkID : 7 // 7 for example
  }
```

It is working well ! But as soon as I replace it with `$stateParams.idCats`, I receive this message coming from the function: No posts available.

Note that there are products using the idCats: 7.

When I log it:

```
console.log("Test Log: " + $stateParams.idCats);
```

This returns the same number: `Test Log: 7`.

If you have any suggestion or a starting point to solve this issue, it will be welcome !

Notice that there are no error in the Console (Both server and client side).

Thank you.

Comment: is $stateParams.idCats a number?

Comment: @SunriseM Yes exactly sir.

Comment: but are you sure it is, it can be a string so that's why its not finding anything. It has happened before to me

Comment: You solved the problem for me when you asked if it's a number ! Many thank's sir, i just added `Number(idCats)` and the problem is solved lol